# Flex ToggleButton - toggle dynamically?

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, togglebutton

I have a four ToggleButton buttons that I want to behave as a group, so when one is clicked the others toggle off. I know you can do this with mx:ToggleButtonBar but I want to to use a spark skin-able component (ToggleButton). Is there a way to toggle a ToggleButton on and off programmatically or is there another way I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read more info here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d9f.html).

I think this is the information you need:

```
For MX controls, if the toggle property is set to true, the state of the Button control does not change until the user releases the mouse button over the control. For the Spark ToggleButton, this statement applies to the selected property.
```

However, it is not clear to be what "on and off" mean in relation to the ToggleButton.  I assume you are relating them to the up and down states.

Comment: I will give this a shot- thx. Yes  I meant "on and off" with regards to the up and down states.